# $a+b+c=9k,\,a≠b≠c,\,a,b,c∈N \, and\, a,b,c<10$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

how do you manage the following?
\begin{equation}
a+b+c=9k,a≠b≠c,a,b,c∈N \, and\, a,b,c<10
\end{equation}
Prove that one of the adders must be multiple of three.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean to say that $c$ also satisfies $c\neq a$? Otherwise that is not true.

Comment: I meant $a \neq c$.

Comment: You only need to consider $10$ triplets $(a,b,c)$ with the assumption that $a\lt b\lt c$. This shouldn't be that hard to prove by exhaustion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we had such a triple $(a,b,c)$.  Suppose, wlog, that $a<b<c$

First work $\pmod 3$.  We have $a+b+c\equiv 0 \pmod 3$.  If $a,b,c$ are distinct $\pmod 3$ then one of them is divisible by $3$.  Thus two, at least, must coincide $\pmod 3$.  Casework shows that we must have all three the same $\pmod 3$, so either we have $a,b,c\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ or we have $a,b,c\equiv -1\pmod 3$.

Say we have $a,b,c\equiv 1\pmod 3$.  Then we must have $a,b,c\in \{1,4,7\}$.  But $1+4+7=12$ is not a multiple of $9$.

Say we have $a,b,c\equiv -1 \pmod 3$.  Then we must have $a,b,c\in \{2,5,8\}$.  But $2+5+8=15$ is not a multiple of $9$.

And we are done.

Comment: Manually checking apart, I think this is the best solution.

Comment: Thank you very much.